"sh: 1: !: not found" in GitHub Actions
I have the following in my Github Actions YAML. It runs fine when the first check evaluates true,
    - name: Check version is up to date
      run: sh -c "
        (git diff --quiet HEAD^ VERSION && git diff --quiet HEAD^ src/**) || \
          ! git diff --quiet HEAD^ src/VERSION
        "

but when it evaluates false, the later sections gives me
sh: 1:  !: not found

only in GitHub Actions. The command starting (and including) sh -c doesn't error on my computer. I don't understand how that could be since I very explicitly mention the shell.

@Ferrybig thanks, I'm familiar with bash vs sh, but is ! bash? And if so, why does it work on my machine even with sh -c?

On your machine, run ls /bin/sh -l, you see it is a symlink to another shell. If you compare the output of this local vs in github actions, you see it is a different shell

you mean sh -c doesn't necessarily run sh? I get sh locally, and dash in github actions. Does this mean github actions symlinks to a different shell that doesn't support the same as sh? If so, wtaf?

it's even symlinked to dash when I add shell: sh

GitHub Actions: Split Long Command into Multiple Lines

When look at the error message, I see extra space before the ! (that is, two space characters between 1: and !). It seems you ask the shell to execute " !" command (with leading space!). Probably, the tailing backslash (\) is the reason of that leading space. Why do you ever need that backslash?

@Tsyvarev the traling backslash is for the multi-line string

This question is similar to: How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Context: As explained in this answer you're using the plain style which doesn't preserve newlines, hence a backslash at the end of your line doesn't work as a line continuation character.

Debug questions require a [mre]-- cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest
representative example input as code; desired & actual output
(including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear
specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is
code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.
(Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where
the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you
expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative
documentation. (Debug fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

I understand the logic behind closing this as a duplicate, but I don't agree with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines may offer many alternative syntaxes that work to achieve what the OP wanted, but without the explanation in @AbdulAzizBarkat's comment, a reader is going to be none the wiser about what was actually wrong with the syntax that the OP used - i.e. how the backslash gets interpreted and how that ultimately leads to the error the OP saw. That explanation belongs in an answer, IMO, not a dupe closure comment.

@philipxy That boilerplate comment gives no hint of what aspect of an MRE you think is missing (and includes some stuff that is nonsensical about variables; there are none here). For reasons I've remarked before (see my answer at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367798/1709587), I find such boilerplate MRE comments unhelpful and obnoxious. If you think the code is non-minimal, say that; if not enough code is given to repro the error, say that; if the expected and actual behavior aren't clear, say that. But none of those things obviously applies, and you don't say which you mean.

@MarkAmery the issue is more about how multi line strings need to be declared in YAML which is the reason for my duplicate closure vote. Perhaps this is a better duplicate target? It should be more obvious with this one since it uses the shell and has a similar problem due to linebreaks not being preserved.

@AbdulAzizBarkat [1/2] IMO a full explanation here needs to address 1. that with the particular YAML string syntax the OP is using, single newlines get ignored / not included in the output when the YAML is parsed, 2. that from the YAML parser's perspective the backslash is simply a backslash character, 3. that, when the shell parses the command, this results in the backslash escaping the space before the !, 4. that this results in trying to run a nonexistent command named  ! instead of just !, and 5. possible ways to fix this.

@AbdulAzizBarkat [2/2] Taken together, and with a little thought and synthesis on the reader's part, the dupe target, the answer here, and your comments spell all this out quite well, but none of them on their own does so; nor will any general question about writing multi-line strings in YAML (It will hit some of the points I list, but leave out any and the reader is liable to walk away mystified.) In my view, that means duplicate closure isn't warranted, though I know many users disagree with this way of thinking and use it more liberally.

I think this is a formatting error/quirk. If I add a new line before the command, with the | syntax, as
      run: |
        sh -c "
        (git diff --quiet HEAD^ VERSION && git diff --quiet HEAD^ src/**) || \
          ! git diff --quiet HEAD^ src/VERSION
        "

it works.

I see, the original YAML results in || \ ! git causing the backslash to escape the space causing the shell to look for an executable that has a space as the first character and ! as the second. The syntax used by the answer preserves the newline causing the backslash to be used for line continuation.
